# increasing cell total votes value swift

Tags: swift

For every cell in my table view, I have an upvote value for the number of upvotes that each cell will have. Right now, I'm increasing the number of upvotes based on the touch of a button that is also inside the cell.  I declared the sweetVotes outlet in the cell subclass.

I keep getting the following error on the "let indexpath:NSIndexpath..." line when I try pressing the button:

```
    *Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)*
```

and this in the log:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Here is my code

```
  @IBAction func upvote(sender: AnyObject) {

        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

        let cell:SweetTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SweetTableViewCell

        var a:Int? = cell.sweetVotes.text?.toInt()
        a = a!+1
        cell.sweetVotes.text = "\(a)"

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the cell does not get selected when you tap the button so `indexPathForSelectedRow` returns `nil`.

You can store the cell's row number in the button's tag at cell creation so you can reference it later (replace `MyCell` with your cell's class):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(...) as MyCell
    ...
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row  // set the row
}
```

Now, when the user taps the button you know the row number:

```
@IBAction func upvote(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row = sender.tag  // The button is the sender
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row, inSection:0)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as MyCell

    var a:Int? = cell.sweetVotes.text?.toInt()
    a = a!+1
    cell.sweetVotes.text = "\(a)"
}
```